# writing contents of a large list with unequal sizes of elements into a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have this list, consisting of ID's, electrode names (starting with FP1, FP2, ect.) and values for these electrodes (the same length as electrode number).
Data from the first three subjects (ID01, ID02,, etc.) are pasted here, , but goes until 300), so the first three elements make up the data for one subject. The second three (of 300) is the second subject, the third three is the third, ....
How to put these into a data frame, so the first column will be ID, the rest of the columns  will be electrode names, and values will fill the corresponding electrode columns? 
Not all subjects have all electrodes, but the target is a list of all electrode names as columns, and NA for subjects who don't have values on all electrodes. The last subject has the full list of all electrodes (n=61).

```
list(structure(c(3.45795372430056, 3.53200270642221, 4.36553103359199, 
3.05971192770099, 3.29632877899404, 3.31308236318143, 4.24725416194864, 
3.66643658172688, 2.73649182050675, 2.86257080026395, 3.45461249221543, 
3.53379688684901, 2.65509461019589, 5.32702317286538, 5.1440372077419, 
8.00426340158606, 3.92566337555864, 2.9636836702809, 7.79363529740775, 
3.42717498319627, 12.5073419593008, 10.3913035195863, 5.44169225429074, 
7.85383530152502, 11.3143739506589, 16.5073444629463, 17.5407670530062, 
12.5893645313808, 17.8699704499684, 8.48272564646519, 3.55173967332533, 
3.26248745488676, 3.47497470296353, 3.62100148748729, 3.18396151227945, 
3.14692007975935, 3.22899853274755, 3.54879001434911, 5.06844813509229, 
2.57729130540013, 3.03469400084275, 4.28207212770906, 4.21050720100374, 
2.18076346859284, 2.40017232044327, 4.90875033326619, 7.16821281572614, 
2.54824918527749, 7.15790382478216, 5.20483882884626, 10.7570196069246, 
7.54524246493832, 4.95407437226951, 11.2942158383124, 22.0250910762801, 
14.0146020891073, 14.2275533653629, 13.2304661228916, 25.3693988199125
), .Dim = c(1L, 59L)), structure("010002", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), 
    list(structure(list(structure("Fp1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("Fp2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("Fz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("Cz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("T8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("AFz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("Pz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO9", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("O1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("Oz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("O2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO10", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("AF7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("AF3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("AF4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("AF8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("F6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FT7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FC4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("FT8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("C6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CPz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("CP4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("TP8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("P6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("POz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), 
        structure(list(structure("PO8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = "")), 
    structure(c(26.8384489065394, 26.178786435345, 24.0696274719001, 
    22.0581009753417, 21.7966235494399, 20.3346419268736, 20.0605899957186, 
    17.7991738540519, 18.7540314511323, 17.9510904574407, 16.8521197344211, 
    19.6842338986443, 18.9743577851434, 21.4202581870846, 19.3416505488144, 
    17.7356454173219, 19.4875220168306, 21.9753445773492, 17.5913570320386, 
    24.5242414281308, 43.8746438160429, 40.3635608443272, 31.4058554541589, 
    40.9379373855574, 49.782682122153, 39.3376883823783, 96.8794416352117, 
    86.1996398947607, 106.634503783336, 38.7159635810776, 26.347589142127, 
    24.7225308421884, 23.4233625744009, 23.5325301411389, 23.0320199288561, 
    21.4952861744385, 20.6886343868372, 20.1221952048054, 20.0772452406375, 
    17.6885410768851, 16.8476207646853, 18.4221038053744, 17.1960298481726, 
    17.1211073274811, 19.1537187755581, 16.5737459444849, 23.8639523921583, 
    19.7756724284431, 20.6199232123305, 23.894234308329, 25.8977179919594, 
    44.7853496906293, 33.6182326942625, 33.6419014416442, 44.6089201552485, 
    92.39219248212, 124.816871412174, 90.0410019162686, 114.824488016676, 
    104.651494384023), .Dim = c(1L, 60L)), structure("010003", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L)), list(structure(list(structure("Fp1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L
    ))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Fp2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Fz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC5", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC6", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Cz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("T8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP5", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP6", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("AFz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Pz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO9", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("O1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("Oz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("O2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO10", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("AF7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("AF3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("AF4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("AF8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F5", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("F6", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FT7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FC4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("FT8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C5", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("C6", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("TP7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CPz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("CP4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("TP8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P5", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P1", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P2", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("P6", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO7", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO3", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("POz", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO4", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(structure("PO8", .Dim = c(1L, 
    1L))), .Names = "")), structure(c(6.52262355115135, 6.46895430321081, 
    9.96846249894624, 5.91667626881474, 5.52951310466457, 5.64831450355776, 
    8.02098150950742, 6.38999209902158, 4.79760752845684, 5.26073757775495, 
    5.08580860086334, 6.24470367065521, 3.94704299223443, 4.16346118185809, 
    4.25535538782261, 8.38621701212565, 6.51193287638641, 3.81564335255996, 
    3.83327398262525, 7.70669254303875, 6.00986043034125, 12.7066628054173, 
    7.23785194772164, 4.48524677154324, 5.75359331597233, 22.0131273871584, 
    11.416930149232, 16.6470763469124, 10.3586383578097, 22.2825021291186, 
    19.6767724196017, 6.69851406360227, 5.86261428741011, 5.89256893341301, 
    7.4236395972263, 6.36962887486336, 5.48924913926016, 5.68968158677107, 
    5.6087195451651, 10.4806687884767, 4.53619567023033, 4.65711761775388, 
    7.19445136113883, 6.16464848622524, 3.78797139799689, 4.09748540901898, 
    5.23320880832957, 11.8566417647642, 4.82329124268468, 3.4392192645961, 
    5.36288682401034, 12.7443548964839, 9.50046297804874, 5.25521906440384, 
    5.77644207387369, 14.6796214279794, 18.1397580727737, 11.7588661192153, 
    8.09118982724719, 12.3338712811978, 25.9414299375728), .Dim = c(1L, 
    61L)), structure("010004", .Dim = c(1L, 1L)), list(structure(list(
        structure("Fp1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("Fp2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("Fz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("T7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("Cz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("T8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("AFz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("Pz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO9", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("O1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("Oz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("O2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO10", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("AF7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("AF3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("AF4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("AF8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("F6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FT7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FC4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("FT8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("C6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("TP7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CPz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("CP4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("TP8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P5", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P1", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P2", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("P6", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO7", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO3", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("POz", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO4", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = ""), structure(list(
        structure("PO8", .Dim = c(1L, 1L))), .Names = "")))
```

In the end I want a dataset like this:

```
structure(list(ID = 11:13, Fp1 = c(1.263922213, 62.32026167, 
NA), Fp2 = c(1.091686849, 62.4886991, NA), F7 = c(0.984334333, 
52.31954112, NA), F3 = c(1.096631569, 51.56342594, NA), Fz = c(1.351514783, 
55.32414052, NA), F4 = c(1.218890315, 52.00981554, NA), F8 = c(0.914644708, 
46.68492663, NA), FC5 = c(0.601500911, 35.56623024, NA), FC1 = c(1.177340834, 
36.6661937, NA), FC2 = c(1.417423697, 39.36278479, NA), FC6 = c(0.683356763, 
32.63064211, NA), T7 = c(1.278134852, 21.10633206, NA), C3 = c(0.512067552, 
13.69190204, NA), Cz = c(1.408020324, 24.46806549, NA), C4 = c(0.81822268, 
13.63535186, NA), T8 = c(0.850876192, 20.05841876, NA), CP5 = c(1.507355579, 
14.74676578, NA), CP1 = c(0.593112661, 15.66113117, NA), CP2 = c(0.792048927, 
11.8129256, NA), CP6 = c(0.681988768, 15.46479391, NA), Afz = c(1.238921666, 
60.94917394, NA), P7 = c(4.75862455, 83.42534527, NA), P3 = c(1.488444506, 
52.65631279, NA), Pz = c(0.747210746, 61.51374412, NA), P4 = c(0.752375408, 
46.99538186, NA), P8 = c(2.538073468, 125.5516832, NA), PO9 = c(8.413214469, 
104.68268, NA), O1 = c(6.367353389, 232.7845208, NA), Oz = c(2.263346576, 
170.7459949, NA), O2 = c(3.10798708, 211.1910123, NA), PO10 = c(3.17989848, 
106.6299255, NA), AF7 = c(1.12513852, 59.08884192, NA), AF3 = c(1.156310804, 
59.35637981, NA), AF4 = c(1.134953069, 58.97170076, NA), AF8 = c(1.150562012, 
56.06065559, NA), F5 = c(0.833960928, 53.59838273, NA), F1 = c(1.353046814, 
52.44991656, NA), F2 = c(1.429154713, 53.76936818, NA), F6 = c(1.008437819, 
50.81219875, NA), FT7 = c(0.974090365, 36.81396512, NA), FC3 = c(0.709146544, 
34.35878924, NA), FC4 = c(1.019948885, 33.34821677, NA), FT8 = c(0.825177004, 
32.26045906, NA), C5 = c(0.663452106, 17.20344674, NA), C1 = c(0.796890294, 
15.99710212, NA), C2 = c(1.051848935, 16.06017515, NA), C6 = c(0.569041657, 
15.74648884, NA), TP7 = c(2.489287907, 17.50258745, NA), CP3 = c(0.801137141, 
12.66043828, NA), CPz = c(0.924721845, 17.94083825, NA), CP4 = c(0.705080811, 
9.451619285, NA), TP8 = c(1.049751438, 31.21243546, NA), P5 = c(2.881512895, 
72.87366809, NA), P1 = c(0.86758872, 52.54723734, NA), P2 = c(0.683790151, 
47.5009376, NA), P6 = c(1.357360304, 86.92030525, NA), PO7 = c(9.037283791, 
290.4541348, NA), PO3 = c(2.86514785, 190.1773559, NA), Poz = c(1.210950625, 
229.3585099, NA), PO4 = c(1.426158747, 185.6488768, NA), PO8 = c(4.372615653, 
296.6505658, NA)), row.names = 11:13, class = "data.frame")
```

I tried many (probably embarrassing) ways only to fail in the first step. I never had to deal with lists, so any help would be greatly appreciated!! thanks

Comment: Hi! Just to make sure I copied your data correctly, is your example data a list of 9, which contains 3 doubles, 3 characters, and 3 lists?

Comment: hey sumshyftw, yes. the first one is values (for electrodes), second one is name for ID, third is the list for electrode names.

Comment: I get a bunch of errors when trying to past that version of `data`.

Comment: I think I fixed it now, you can name and paste it into a script file

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to figure out how to use `lapply` in an elegant way to shape your data how I wanted it, but I opted to use a `for` loop instead (maybe someone else could find a nicer way to do this!). The general logic behind this was to unlist your list to get a dataframe I could work with, and then use `tidyverse` to reshape your data.frame.

```
NewList <- vector("list", length(data)/3)

for (i in 1:(length(data)/3)) {
  NewList[[i]] <- as.data.frame(t(rbind(unlist(data[[3*i - 2]]), unlist(data[[3*i - 1]]), unlist(data[[3*i]]))))
}

NewDF <- rbindlist(check)
colnames(NewDF) = c("value", "ID", "electrode")

CleanedData <- NewDF %>% group_by(electrode, ID) %>% mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% spread(electrode, value)
CleanedData$ind <- NULL
```

The code above requires `data.table` and `tidyverse` packages to work, but all I'm doing is unlisting and binding your data in packets of 3 (I'm assuming the rest of your data follows the same pattern as the sample data) and allocating each "packet" as a dataframe to a nested list. I then bind all of those dataframes together to make `NewDF`.

Afterwards, I use the `tidyverse` package to make each electrode a column name and spread them based on the values and IDs.

Hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: thanks a lot for spending time on this!! I tried it now but the for loop throws this error "Error in rbind(unlist(data[[3 * i - 2]]), unlist(data[[3 * i - 1]]), unlist(data[[3 *  : 
  number of columns of matrices must match (see arg 2)".

Comment: Within `data`, what data types do the elements appear as? In the example, I had them appearing as a double, a character, and a list.

Comment: hey sumshyftw, yes, exactly the same. double, character, list respectively

Comment: Oddly enough, when I copy/pasted your test data in my console again (I had previously copy/pasted it before your edit) it gave me different data types for the elements. What was previously the `ID01` character appeared as a list that contained all three IDs. My solution then did not work on this new data. Was this intentional?

Comment: strange indeed. I had only changed a few characters in the ID column, and since a user commented that the code (data) gives errors when pasted, I edited it and pasted the data as it appeared in my workspace. I didn't think adding the marker ID in front of these numbers in ' ' would make a difference. sorry for taking your time if that was my fault really!

Comment: No worries, but are you still getting the same error with your data?

Comment: yes :/ I solved the problem in the end myself, but in a very not elegant way I suppose! so I would still be curious about a nicer/tidier solution :)